# Integral of a trigonometric function with an argument of linear function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to know how to do the following integral:
$$\int\dfrac{\sin^2(y)}{\sin(x-y)}dy,$$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Wolfram Mathemtica solves it as follows:
$$\cos(s + x) + \sin^2(s) \left( \log\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{s - x}{2}\right)\right) - \log\left(\sin\left(\dfrac{s - x}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$
but I don't know how.

Thanks for all.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It depends on whether x is related to y or is an arbitrary constant. Which is it?

Comment: In particular, $y\in(\pi/2,\pi)$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Try to use $u=x-y$ and then $\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$.

Comment: Or use the fun identity $(\sin y - \sin x)(\sin y + \sin x) = \sin(y+x)\sin(y-x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize
$\sin^2 y =\sin^2 x - \sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)$ to integrate as follows

\begin{align}\int\dfrac{\sin^2y}{\sin(x-y)}dy
=&\ \sin^2x \int\frac{1}{\sin(x-y)}dy-\int\sin(x+y)\ dy\\
=& \ \sin^2x \ \ln\cot\frac{x - y}{2}+\cos(x + y) 
\end{align}